# Iterating using for-each

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, iterator

```
for (String str : m.keySet()) {//this works fine

    }
```

---

```
Set set = m.keySet();
for (String str : set) {//Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

    }
```

Both are doing same thing i.e iterating over Keys(String) of Set object than why i am getting error in second code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use the raw `Set` type, since in that case the elements of the `Set` would be assumed to be of `Object` type.

Instead, specify the type of elements the `Set` holds :

```
Set<String> set = m.keySet();
for (String str : set) {

}
```

Comment: And what happens in first case, how compiler knows about which type of Set we are using ?.

Comment: @JavedSolkar `m.keySet()` probably returns a `Set<String>`, which means that the type of `m` is probably `Map<String,Something>`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because Set doesnot know which type to be used so its throwing exception you have to use `String` as generic feed for it. like below snippet

```
Set<String> set = m.keySet();
```